# Efficient Multi-thread downloading?

Tags: connection, threads

My downloading speed of files is not fast enough..
Is there any way to add more thread in a single download?

Thank you for answering this.

Comment: try using various download manager available?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I have both wire and wireless connection on my computer, any good suggestion?

Comment: Because chrome and firefox doesn't provide multi-connection download for files. Usually Download manager provides these functionality.

Comment: wait, are you trying to download multiple documents at once, or just a single document?

Answer (score 1):

Your download speed has a few different factors that make up for the total download speed.

1. Your internet `up` and `download` speed. (yes, both are equally important.)
2. How many clients are connected to this internet, and how active are they using it?
3. How fast is the server where you're downloading from?
4. Where is the server you're downloading from located?
5. How are you connected to the internet? Is it through a LAN cable or WIFI?
6. Are you downloading with other programs on your computer?
7. Are you downloading with a single connection or with multiple?

The first thing you want to do is do a speedtest to determine how well your internet connection is. If the speedtest gives a low speed here, there's nothing you can do unless it is below of what you should be getting normally, in which case you need to call your ISP and report that the connection is not up to par.

Also do note that if the upload speed is reaching its full capacity, the download will stall and that will be seen as a laggy and slow connection. The reason is that for every downloaded packet, one is uploaded to send an "I got it" message (acknowledgement packet) back to the origin.

Secondly, you need to verify how many other people are using the same internet, and what they're doing on it while you download. If they use torrent or other stuff that either uses a lot of download or upload speed, you are limited by that.

Thirdly, you need to verify if the server itself is not being slow. Because if they are, there's nothing you can do about it. You can test this by downloading from another server, if possible one in your country near you that you know is supposed to be fast.

Fourthly, as said before, where is the server located? Even if that server is a fast server, but it is on the other side of the world, it will have an increased delay for each series of packets, because once you downloaded some, you have to send an acknowledgement back. This makes it so that long-distant downloads are slow to come to a high speed, and are more prone to errors causing the connection to reset making it slow again.

Fifthly, You already mentioned that you have both cable and wifi. Do note that wifi is always slow, so if you use both, it still is possible that you're browsing over wifi. So turn off wifi, and try again, just to make sure.

Sixthly, Do you use something like torrent on your own computer? Or downloading windows updates or other stuff? email, etc? If so, temporarily stop anything that downloads and see if that helps.

And lastly, You mention you are using Chrome. Are you using the latest version? If so, you should be downloading with 6 connections at a time, if the server supports this. If you were to download with just one connection at a time, a download manager would maybe be useful, but I doubt that's the case.